# ActiveRecord includes array of tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have an over-complicated data-structure. So the bullet gem screams "N+1 QUERIES" at me, and advise to include seven tables in my query.

I know that in reality, it's more than that, so I need to do something like this:

```
to_include = [:cars, :dishes, :sheets, :vegetables, :clothes]
data = SuperMarket.where(place: @here).includes(:cars, :dishes, :sheets, :vegetables, :clothes)
```

using the to_include array dynamically for the includes.

I know that the architecture is the real problem here. I just want to know if ActiveRecord can save me once again.

Comment: Can you pass an array to includes? Sure.

Comment: it you use rails 4 you dont need bullet gem

Comment: @DavidAldridge You're right, copy paste it in an answer so I can validate it !